# Debt of a deceased person

Tags: debt

A friend of mine recently passed away. Before his demise he had told his brother that he was in debt to a lot of people. He told his brother the debt amounted to 25-30 thousand rupees. The deceased never mentioned any names or contact information of the people he owed money to. Kindly let me know as to what the brother can do in this situation. How much money should he pay and to whom should he pay?

Comment: This is not a fatwa site.

Comment: In case if debt the whole debt must be paid unless these people forgoe with a clean heart. And if the brother knows any of those people he should contact them first and ask them about the others etc. This is simply how we've practiced this in case of brother who died as a student in foreign country after asking a scholar.